# Too many global variables/functions with ":optimizations :advanced"

Tags: javascript, clojurescript, leiningen, google-closure-compiler, bundling-and-minification

From my web app, When compile with code with ":optimizations :none", there are around ~300 global items on "window" object after loading all js file into browser

However, when compile code with ":optimizations :advanced", there are ~10K global items (functions and objects).

Seems like minification strategy is making everything global. Is there a way to change its behavior?

Here is a repro [repo](https://github.com/shrimpy/lein-cljsbuild/blob/module-test/example-projects/advanced/project.clj#L61)

Run "lein do clean &&  lein cljsbuild once" and check "lein-cljsbuild/example-projects/advanced/resources/public/js/main-debug.js"

#

Update:
Reason ":output-wrapper" doesn't work for my case was I am using ":modules" in my build config and one module will depend on another. Compiler cannot wrap module with (function(){})(), since it will break the dependency. e.g Module foo have to access var bar from module bar.

Comment: @DanielCompton Because it put everything into global scope.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the `:output-wrapper` compiler option:
https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#output-wrapper

Comment: it doesn't work for my case. here is a repro https://github.com/shrimpy/lein-cljsbuild/tree/module-test

Comment: `output_wrapper` is the correct answer here. @XiaominWu your are going to have to be more specific about why it doesn't work.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth updated my post. It was because i am using ":modules"

Comment: paste the repo link again

https://github.com/shrimpy/lein-cljsbuild/tree/module-test/example-projects/advanced

Comment: There is an undocumented flag: `rename_prefix_namespace` for just this case. https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CommandLineRunner.java#L673-L676

Comment: Thanks Chad, turn out that flag is not expose in clojure script compiler, which we cannot use it. I opened an issue on CLJS Jira https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-2337